# How to access other fields on a three way pivot in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Here's what my architecture looks like:

[image]

The idea is that a user have a role on a given group. Of course, the user belongs to many groups, and a user can have multiple roles (in different groups)

I'm trying to get all the groups a user belongs to.

Please forgive me for not using the convention to name the pivot table as groups_roles_users, I decided this way for readability.

So, in the User model I say:

```
public function groups() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Group', 'roles_in_groups');
}
```

In a view I do:

```
@foreach ($user->groups as $group)
  {{ $group->name }}
@endforeach
```

works perfectly.

Now I want to access the `roles` table. I want to print something like: **`In {{ $group->name }} you're a {{ $group->role->name }}`**, obviously, It doesn't work like that.

If I use the `pivot` property, it will give me only the `user_id` and `group_id`, not even the `role_id` to search with an static method.

SO, how can I accomplish that?

I'm using Laravel 5.7

Comment: What does your group model look like? Does it have the role relation

Comment: Yes it had it. It was called roles.

Comment: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_in_group');` but if I call `$group->roles` it returns a collection (all the roles for that group) so I can't call `$group->roles->role_id`

Comment: Yeah it won't because its has many roles you would have to loop over the roles also printing each role name

Comment: But that's not what I want. I want to get the name of the rol for the user in that specific group

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
public function roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role', 'roles_in_groups');
}

$user = \User::with(['roles','groups'])->first();
$role_name = $user->role->name  
$group_name = $user->group->name
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Interesting! I'll try that. Right now, I'm solving it with another function in the User model, but I thought it could be done using only the ORM. I'll try your code